# Setting SVN configurations to deny anonymous access

Tags: svn, raspberry-pi, tortoisesvn, raspbian

I am trying to configure a svn server in a Raspberry Pi, such as I can list the repositories path in a browser, but only to pi user. Others access cannot be allowed, even for read-only.

So I configured `/etc/apache2/dav_svn.authz` as

```
[/]
*=
pi=rw

[svn:/]
*=
pi=rw
```

And `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dav_svn.conf`

```
<Location /svn>
  DAV svn
  SVNListParentPath on
  SVNParentPath /media/usbhdd1/db
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Repositories"
  AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd
  AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.authz
  Require valid-user
</Location>
```

There are occurring 2 problems. One in the browser, the other in simple checkout.

In the browser, the problem is that if I access the parent folder using http://.../svn/, it asks for the user/password, so this is ok. But when I access directly the repository myrepo from http://.../svn/myrepo, it does not ask for user/password, so the repository contents is exposed.

In checkout, it does not authenticate. In this case, when I try to checkout using TortoiseSVN, it returns the errors:

> Unable to connect to a repository at URL
>
> 'http://192.168.0.200:8888/svn/myrepo'
>
> Unexpected HTTP status 405
>
> 'Method Not Allowed' on '/svn/myrepo'
>
> Additional errors:
>
> The URI does not contain the name of a repository.

What could I have missed?

Answer (score 1):

Unrelated (but existing) errors

- Access rights in dav_svn.authz are inherited form root to descendants: you must to **redefine** only **changed rules**, but for **repository** `svn` you *cloned parent rights*, `[svn:/]` is absolutely useless
- [NAME:/] in section name define (existing) repository-name, not Location from Apache, thus - for repository `myrepo` (which is, physically, directory `/media/usbhdd1/db`) `[svn:/]` section from dav_svn.authz have no sense at all

  1. Check your client's Subversion auth-cache, clean it, if needed.
  2. Use known, existing repository
  3. If you want to have authorization dialogue every time, not once per client, read about `store-auth-creds` in subversion config